# How does Siverlight 5 with P/Invoke compare to XBAP with FullTrust?

Tags: silverlight, pinvoke, xbap, silverlight-5.0, full-trust

I'm considering XBAP with full trust, but just heard about SL5's ability to P/Invoke.  This is quite exciting because XBAP deployments are very difficult considering it only really works with IE, works sometimes with Firefox, and never with chrome.

Does anyone have details on this feature, and its cross browser support (on an x86 machine of course)

Comment: Another disadvantage of XBAP is that it requires a particular version of .NET installed on the client (3.0?), which is a couple orders of magnitude larger than Silverlight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some examples of using P/Invoke on Silverlight 5 RC [here](http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2011/09/silverlight-5-rc-released-using-pinvoke.html) and [here](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2011/09/05/silverlight-5-rc-platform-invocation.aspx). Just today I [posted](http://cureos.blogspot.com/2011/09/pinvoke-bundling-native-dlls-in.html) on my blog regarding the possibility to access native DLL:s other than the regular system DLL:s.

I normally run Chrome, and Silverlight P/Invoke works like a charm. I assume that IE should not be any problem either. Have to admit I have not tested Firefox or Opera, but maybe someone else has some experience with this?

Regards,

Anders @ Cureos